# How can I compare two C# collections and issue Add, Delete commands to make them equal?

Tags: c#

I have two ICollection collections:

```
public partial class ObjectiveDetail
{
    public int ObjectiveDetailId { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

var _objDetail1: // contains a list of ObjectiveDetails from my database.
var _objDetail2: // contains a list of ObjectiveDetails from web front end.
```

How can I iterate through these and issue and Add, Delete or Update to synchronize the database with the latest from the web front end?

If there is a record present in the first list but not the second then I would like to:

```
_uow.ObjectiveDetails.Delete(_objectiveDetail);
```

If there is a record present in the second list but not the first then I would like to:

```
_uow.ObjectiveDetails.Add(_objectiveDetail);
```

If there is a record (same ObjectiveDetailId) in the first and second then I need to see if they are the same and if not issue an:

```
_uow.ObjectiveDetails.Update(_objectiveDetail);
```

I was thinking to do this with some kind of:

```
foreach (var _objectiveDetail in _objectiveDetails) {}
```

but then I think I might need to have two of these and I am also wondering if there is a better way. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I could do this?

Comment: So the order of the items isn't important, right? And can the items be repeated?

Comment: so basically you want common in both?

Comment: Yes I need what's in the database to match the front-end. If something is not there any more in the database then it needs to be removed. Note all the items newly addon the front-end will have an ObjectiveDetailId of 0.

Comment: Why don't you just set the front end to equal a copy of the database.

Comment: Adding to It'sNotALie: old items could have changed. There isn't only added and deleted. There is added, deleted, changed

Comment: Okay yeah I see your point. Yes I need to also process _uow.ObjectiveDetails.Update for a change. I updated the question. I am sorry I did not realize this was needed.

Comment: The front end will be a copy of the database but then code in the front-end allows the user to add, update and delete the detail records. When the user clicks Save it is all sent back to the back end and then processed here. I guess this is a pretty common thing and I was hoping others had found a good way to do this processing. Thanks

Comment: @Alan you mention that you are using entity framework in one of the comments, is `ObjectiveDetail` a Entity Frameork object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code is one of some possible solutions

```
var toBeUpdated =
            objectiveDetail1.Where(
            a => objectiveDetail2.Any(
                b => (b.ObjectiveDetailId == a.ObjectiveDetailId) && 
                     (b.Number != a.Number || !b.Text.Equals(a.Text))));

var toBeAdded =
            objectiveDetail1.Where(a => objectiveDetail2.All(
            b => b.ObjectiveDetailId != a.ObjectiveDetailId));

var toBeDeleted =
            objectiveDetail2.Where(a => objectiveDetail1.All(
            b => b.ObjectiveDetailId != a.ObjectiveDetailId));
```

The rest is a simple code to Add, Delete, Update the three collections to the database.

Answer (score 1):

It's look like you just want the two lists to be a copy of one another, you can just implement a Copy method and replace the outdated collection, if you implement ICollection you will need to implement CopyTo, also you can add a version field to the container so you can know if you need to update it.
If you don't want to do it this way and you want to go through the elements and update them check if you can save in each object the state (modified, deleted, updated) this will help in the comparison.

Comment: Yes I think this is what I am looking for but I am not sure how to implement anything like this.

Comment: It's depend you want the update to also update your db or just the object in memory?

Comment: Well if I can update the object that would be okay as I can delete that object from the database and then add it all again using Entity Framework.

Comment: there are two options: 1) You can iterate through the collection, if you chose to do so it's preferred to do so in a way faster then O(n) if the collection is sorted it is easy to be done. 2) You can define the object as value type (use struct instead of class) and upon copying it will copy the value instead of the reference, notice that if you want the elements of it to be deep copied they also need to be value type

Answer (score -1):

> foreach (var _objectiveDetail in _objectiveDetails) {}  but then I
>   think I might need to have two of these and I am also wondering if
>   there is a better way. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I
>   could do this?

instead of looping through whole collection use LINQ query:

```
var query = from _objectiveDetail in _objectiveDetails
```

`where (condition)
    select ... ;`

**update:**
It's pointless to iterate through whole collection if you want to update/delete/add something from web end. Humans are a bit slower than computers, isn't it? Do it one by one. In fact I don't understand the idea of 2 collections. What is it for? If you still want it: use event to run query, select updated/deleted/added record, do appropriate operation on it.

Comment: But how can my LINQ query generate Add, Update and Delete for the ones needed to get them in sync ?

Comment: use query result as a parameter

Comment: You're crazy if you think you can do this with LINQ.

Comment: I am not thinking I can. I would like to think there's a way but really just looking for suggestions from someone who has maybe had to do this kind of thing before.

Comment: @Alan I'm talking to the answerer, not you :P

Comment: Crazy? this is the simplest solution: query a collection with LINQ and modyfy database using result.

Comment: Na Na - Can you give an example. I know LINQ is very powerful but I am not sure about what it can do.